# How to get Facebook user id from user's phone no

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, mobile

Is it possible to search for a Facebook user by their mobile no. same as we do using email address:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=EMAILADDRESS&type=user&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN